# vector as an argument for recursive function in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, c++17, function-definition

I want to have function like one in the title, but when I declare it like this,

```
void function(vector<int> tab, int n)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        tab.push_back(n);
        function(tab, n - 1);
    }
}
```

it isn't working, because *tab* is still blank.

Comment: You're passing by value, you need to pass by reference.

Comment: There should be a FAQ question about passing by value to make questions like this duplicate of it. This is third question I see just in last 2 days about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're taking `tab` by value - each recursive call will operate on a new copy of `tab`.

You'll want to pass `tab` by reference:

```
void function(std::vector<int>& tab, int n) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you need to declare the first parameter as having the referenced type `std::vector<int> &` like

```
void function( std::vector<int> &tab, int n);
```

Or you should redefine the function such a way that it will return a vector.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> function( int n )
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    return n > 0 ? v = function( n - 1 ), v.push_back( n ), v : v;
}

int main()
{
    auto v = function( 10 );

    for (auto &item : v)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify a vector that was declared outside the scope of your function you should pass it by reference

```
void function(vector<int>& tab, int n)
```

Otherwise each call to `function` will create a function-local copy of `tab` and only mutate that copy, not the original external vector.